# Combining multiple jQuery plugins into one file causes errors

Tags: jquery

I want to compress my jQuery plugins into one file, for convinience and bandwidth saving. I used [Online YIU Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/yui) for that, with "File" option. I uploaded following jQuery plugins:

1. MetaData
2. Form
3. Starrating
4. Validate
5. Additional methods for Validate
6. Polish messages
7. Chosen
8. jTruncate
9. Corners
10. jQuery UI

My problem is, after doing so, couple of them doesn't work, eg. jTruncate returns error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jTruncate'` while used on element, and Validate causes `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`, both printed in console. Corners plugin doesn't work at all (PHPStorm sees the method `corner`, but it doesn't work on output).

What can I do to have those files combined and - if possible - compressed?

Comment: Do these plugins work together if you include all of them (but separately) on a page?

Comment: Yes, they work without a single problem.

Comment: What happens if you include the full-blown jTruncate file while you keep the others compressed? Are the other files showcasing the same issue?

Comment: It works if I include it after compressed `plugins.js`. Same goes for `Validate`.